# set iOS app language from server side

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, localization

I want set my app language from server side. Is this possible? And Is this allowed in AppStore? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Afaik, not easy by default, but [this link](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.se/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html) may help.

Comment: What do you mean by from server side? want to send which lang to use from web service yes it is allowed.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that link you mentioned is helpful. but is this allowed in APPSTORE?

Comment: @amar But i am using native app. And i want set language though programatically. So is it allowed?

Comment: @amar But i am using native app. And i want set language and also text to labels programatically. So is it allowed?

Comment: @AmitB Not sure it's explicit in the AppStore rules, but I have several applications on my iDevices that allow in-app language changes. I cannot see how doing it from the server would be any different.

Comment: Why should this make sense? If its an WebApp, ok, but for a regular native app, with "hardcoded" UI elements?